# What is the best way to deploy containers from pipeline for traefik 2 to manage?

Tags: docker, devops, traefik

I'm having a really hard time to find a better way to deploy a "conteinerized" project to my server. Here's a description of my problem:

**What i have:**

1. AWS EC2 server
2. Traefik V2 to manage and route my containers with https (with Route53 dns server)
3. Travis CI
4. Github
5. Docker Hub

Here's what i'm trying to do:

[image]

I have to set traefik labels in Dockerfile so the docker-compose file use this Dockerfile to build the image (if a set the labels in docker-compose and push it to the registry it doesnt appear).
I dont think this is a really good design, there's problably a better way to solve this.

**What i want to know is that if anyone have a better solution for this !**

Heres the docker-compose for my traefik (followed the config of a tutorial):

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.1
    container_name: traefik2
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    environment:
      # variable for dns server...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`domain.info`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=user:asdasdasdas"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`domain.info`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=mgcresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Here's a react project that i want to serve with this configuration and the Dockerfile and docker-compose that i'm using:

https://github.com/wallysoncarvalho/portfolio-react

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to leverage [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) instead of running Docker containers directly on an EC2 instance. ECS is an AWS managed Docker service, it can run on either EC2 or Fargate infrastructure. It is generally advisable to leverage an existing cloud service when available rather than implement the traditional on-premise alternative.

Here's what a simple build/release workflow would look like:

[image]

Furthermore, I'd also suggest looking into hosting the Docker image in [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) instead of DockerHub, this service integrates well with ECS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I saw this a lot in my searches, but I didn't look at it because I'm just beginning. But from what I understand ECS is an orchestrator like Kubernetes? if so, wouldn't it be better to use K8s, given that you can use it in another cloud service, because with ECS you would be stuck only with AWS, right?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, ECS is an orchestrator like Swarm and K8s and it's AWS proprietary. If you wanted to use K8s you could also use AWS EKS (note that K8s is very much overkill for this particular use case). I wouldn't recommend running an orchestrator on EC2; this defeats many of the advantages of IaaS. I would recommend committing to a cloud provider and taking advantage of the options they provide, remember there's no binding contract.

Comment: I dont think ECS is going to resolve my problem because i'm using traefik 2 to route my containers/services. I tried the same approach with jenkins but i'm algo going to have to ssh into my EC2 and i'm having a hard time. For me, it looks like i'm seeing all of this wrong (build and deploy an app). Could you give me some tips, pls ?